# How do I perform RM scheduling?

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems, systems-engineering

The question says, "Perform RM scheduling for the following task set: T1=(2, 0.5, 4), T2=(3, 1, 10), T3=(5, 1, 10) and T4=(7, 0.45, 15)".

Here the standard notation (Period, execution time, relative deadline) is used.

I understand that the priority will be as follows: T1, T2, T3, T4

In this case, job T1 is released consuming time 0 to 0.5 and then job T2 is released consuming time 0.5 to 1.5. At 2, job 1 needs to be released again and hence I cannot release job T3 from 1.5 to 2.5. Can I skip priorities and release job T4 from 1.5 to 1.95?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: @Wasabi Edited accordingly.